# Setting Path and SameSite Attribute to All cookies of my Application

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I am working on an ASP.Net Webforms Application. My security guy wants all cookies to have Path and SameSite attribute. I can set Path and SameSite attribute to the cookies which i have created but how do set it on Session Cookie. FOr eg whenver a visitor visits my site i set some Session Variables to ASP.net generates a session cookie on Get Request, how Do i set path and SameSite attribute on First Get Request. Is there any Global.asax event which i can use. I have tried using `Application_PreSendRequestHeaders` event like below

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders()
{

    foreach (string str in Response.Cookies.AllKeys)
    {
        HttpCookie ck = Request.Cookies[str];
        ck.Path = "/DBTDASHBOARD";
        ck.Value+=";SameSite=Strict";

    }
}
```

But this works on subsequent requests and not the first get call made to my landing page. Any help would be of great use.

Comment: tried this but it won't set the path. it's still "/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to do this with the help of url reweite 2.0 module for IIS.

Comment: hi @Gagan, how did you do it? by setting paths for your cookies?

Comment: It should be very easy with url rewrite 2.0 module for IIS. I will post the link in next comment

Comment: yes please post the link, thank you so much

Comment: Could you pls share your email, I will send the relevant code on email.

Comment: i'll be waiting . thank you